# Which folder should I store the .m file in order to run it using MEvaluate[MScript["scriptname"]]?

Tags: packages, files-and-directories, matlink

I have installed *MATLink* and it works fine.

Which folder should I store the 'scriptname.m' file, in order to run it using `MEvaluate[MScript["scriptname"]]`?

Answer (score 3):

> Which folder should I store the `scriptname.m` file, in order to run it `using MEvaluate[MScript["scriptname"]]`?

You shouldn't run arbitrary scripts this way.  If the script was not created with `MScript`, simply use

```
MEvaluate["scriptname"]
```

In that case, `scriptname` will be searched for [on the MATLAB path](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/path.html).

---

When the script is created using the two-argument form of [`MScript`](http://matlink.org/documentation/), it is saved into a temporary directory and is usable only for the duration of the session.  This is why placing files into that directory appears to make them accessible through `MScript`.  However, please do not do this.  `MScript` is not meant to be used this way.